# Rails route to only index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This might be a simple routing question in Rails but I have searched around and received answers for Rails 2 rather than Rails 3.

I generated a scaffold and the

```
resources :users
```

which includes new, edit, show are routed together with the index.

I only want to route to the index and remove the new, edit, show etc.
I have already removed the html.erb files but they are still being routed.

Any advice on what I should do to remove the other routes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use the `only` option:

```
resources :users, only: [:index]
```

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created)

Comment: Or if you want to add only one route to resource, you may skip brackets and write like this `resources :users, only: :index`

Answer (score 14):

See Chapter 4.6 of the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

> By default, Rails creates routes for the seven default actions (index, show, new, create, edit, update, and destroy) for every RESTful route in your application. You can use the :only and :except options to fine-tune this behavior. The :only option tells Rails to create only the specified routes:

```
resources :photos, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Comment: if I add `resources :photos, :only => [:index, :show]` in routes, and hit '/photos/new' it routes to photos#show with id='show'.
How do I route :new/:edit routes to 404? Please help

Comment: @waqarmirza you can add constrains to the `show` route to limit the `/:id` to be a integer